# Christmas Lights on a Metal Roof

Tags: lighting, outdoor, metal-roof

Does anyone have any experience with metal roofs and Christmas lights? I've got icicle lights and red C9 lights. The icicle lights I was able to use my shingle hooks and place between a foam padding under the metal roof, and the decking, so that's not a problem, but I'd like to get the red lights to be displayed along the outside edge, and along the ridges.

Some ideas I've seen are magnetic clips, or magnetic lights, but for $0.70/clip, or $1/light, I'd be spending at least $150 for my 200 ft of light clips. I may just have to eat the cost for this.

If needed, I can throw some pics of my roof up once it's day time, but I'm running out of time for this season, so I thought I'd ask.

Here's the C9 bulbs.

[image: http://scene7.targetimg1.com/is/image/Target/12696666?wid=410&hei=410]

Comment: I've ordered [these clips](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00O99MMNQ/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). I'll post it as the answer if it works out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [magnetic clips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O99MMNQ) I purchased held all season. They cost a lot more than just a plain plastic clip-on, but they also go up rather quickly and don't break as easily.

Answer (score 0):

How about binder clips and small individual magnets? Or, you can just use the binder clips to the edge of the roof.

Comment: That might work along the edges, but there's no place to attach it on the ridges. Also, I tried a magnet roll cut and glued to lights, but the magnets were not strong enough.